# How to make global type for all types of integer value types and to know their types in C++

Tags: c++

I like to make function which get by reference variable from any integer (float , int , double ..) to as custom type . This type should know which type it was constructed from. For example, say I build my custom type

```
class Variable
{
   public:
      Variable(int &v)
      Variable(float &v)
      Variable(double &v)
      Variable(short &v)

      void setNuwValue(int &v)
      void setNuwValue(float &v)
      void setNuwValue(double &v)
      void setNuwValue(short &v)

       var_type_enum getType();
};
```

Now in my app I have function which takes this Variable type as an argument

```
void modifyVar(Variable& var)
{
   //1.how to know the var type it can return enum of types or string what ever ..
    var_type_enum type  = var.getType();
    var.setNuwValue(3);  
}
```

As you you can see this is only pseudo code without the implementation which I don't know how to implement and I need help. 
In short I want to be able to implement global type var as used in for example javascript "var" type

Comment: Can a `Variable` change type at runtime? Maybe you want a `boost::variant`?

Comment: what do you mean ? once i set it in the compilation no need to change the type , only its value

Comment: If you want it like that, you can create a variable of each type in an `union`. From there, go your way. Less than 5 lines for each function.

Comment: We know what you want to do but what is the question itself? Because your code looks quite good for basic implementation so far. Secondly why you wan't to pass this types by reference? And at last double and float are not integer types ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
enum VT
{
  VT_int,
  VT_float,
  VT_double,
  VT_short
}

class Variable
{

  int i;
  float f;
  double d;
  short s;

  VT type;
public:
  Variable() : i(0), f(0), d(0), s(0) {}
  Variable(int &v) { i = v; type = VT_int; }
  Variable(float &v) { f = v; type = VT_float; }
  Variable(double &v) { d = v; type = VT_double; }
  Variable(short &v) { s = v; type = VT_short; }

  void setNuwValue(int &v) { i = v; type = VT_int; }
  void setNuwValue(float &v) { f = v; type = VT_float; }
  void setNuwValue(double &v) { d = v; type = VT_double; }
  void setNuwValue(short &v) { s = v; type = VT_short; }

  VT getType() const { return type; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can make use of templates as shown below.

```
template<typename T> class Variable
{
public:

    const char* getType()
    {
        return typeid(T).name();
    }
    void setNuwValue( const T& ValueIn )
    {
        m_Value = ValueIn;
    }

private:

    T m_Value;
};

template<typename T>
void modifyVar(Variable<T>& var)
{
    const char* type = var.getType();
    var.setNuwValue(3);  
}
```

Below example call will return "double" when getType() is called.

```
Variable<double>Var;
modifyVar( Var );
```

Comment: I'm totally sure, that this is not what the OP wants. Can you set a double to a template<int> without conversion issues during run-time or the way around ? That is what the OP wants.

Comment: I understand that OP mainly wants to get type-name. Since OP has given multiple constructors, an object of Variable is supposed to hold numeric value in a single variable and thats why I went for using templates.